# Many Keycloak quick-starts fail on test phase

Tags: java, maven, jboss, keycloak

For example, when running `mvn install wildfly:deploy` on [app-profile-saml-jee-jsp](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-profile-saml-jee-jsp) quick-start, I get the error below.

Trying to run the same on `app-profile-jee-vanilla` quick start fails on tests as well.

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Error:

-------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
------------------------------------------------------- Running org.keycloak.quickstart.ArquillianProfileSamlJeeJspTest Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.491 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.keycloak.quickstart.ArquillianProfileSamlJeeJspTest org.keycloak.quickstart.ArquillianProfileSamlJeeJspTest  Time elapsed:
0.49 sec  <<< ERROR! **java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor**   at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:166)  at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:103)  at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)   at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:114)   at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) **Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null**   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:162)  at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:103)  at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)   at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:114)   at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) **Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerCreationException: Could not create Container jboss**    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:85)    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerRegistryCreator.createRegistry(ContainerRegistryCreator.java:78)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)     at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.bindAndFire(ManagerImpl.java:265)     at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.InstanceImpl.set(InstanceImpl.java:74)    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationRegistrar.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationRegistrar.java:73)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)     at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:290)   at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:63)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:162)  at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:103)  at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)   at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:114)   at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DeployableContainer must be specified**   at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:44)     at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.(ContainerImpl.java:71)  at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:80)    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerRegistryCreator.createRegistry(ContainerRegistryCreator.java:78)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)     at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.bindAndFire(ManagerImpl.java:265)     at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.InstanceImpl.set(InstanceImpl.java:74)    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationRegistrar.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationRegistrar.java:73)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)     at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:290)   at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:63)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:162)  at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:103)  at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)   at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:114)   at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running with `mvn clean install -Pwildfly-managed -Denforcer.skip=true` should fix your issue, if you don't want to run the integration tests , you can skip them `mvn clean install -DskipTests`.

I will update the READMEs to make it more explicit.

Comment: Why are the tests failing?

Comment: Because the `wildfly-managed` profile must be used to be able to run the tests.

Comment: Skipping the tests was enough to make it work - `-DskipTests`.